# shiny + rCharts - object 'input' not found

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I'm trying to embed an rCharts inside of a Shiny and have run into a problem. So this Shiny app works fine -

```
require(shiny)
require(rCharts)

server<-function(input, output) {
 output$chart <- renderChart2({
   n<-nPlot(~ Sepal.Width ,data=iris,group='Species',type='multiBarChart')
   return(n)
  })}

ui<-pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Shiny + rCharts"),
   sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId="columnName",label="Column Selection:",choices=names(iris))
   ),

  mainPanel(
   showOutput("chart", "nvd3")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

But I'd like to change the `server` to be reactive and plot the user-select column from the `ui`. So I might change it to this

```
server<-function(input, output) {
  output$chart <- renderChart2({
  n<-nPlot(~input$columnName ,data=iris,group='Species',type='multiBarChart')
  return(n)
 })}
```

but here the `input$columnName` isn't getting evaluated correctly within the environment of the `rChart` - I get the error *object 'input' not found*. Any thoughts on how to achieve the desired functionality? If I were using `ggplot` here, the right answer would be to switch to using `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`, but I'm not sure what the solution is with `rCharts`. Thanks

Comment: Can you try removing ~ operator?

Comment: That didn't work -  the tilde is the  typical syntax for using `nPlot`- for example `nPlot(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars,type="scatterChart")` .

Comment: You need to convert it into a formula object. So try `f = as.formula(~  input$columnName)` and then `nPlot(f, ...)`.